# Performance on Pinned CPU cores versus automatically managed?

Tags: performance, xenserver, performance-tuning, vcpu

I have a XenServer 7.5 environment where I'm running a single Windows VM with 16 total vCPU's. My server has dual Xeon E5-2620v4 CPU's with 8cores/16threads each clocked at 2.1GHz nominal and a Max Turbo at 3GHz.

My question is whether allowing the CPU's to be automatically managed by XenServer will be better performing, or pinning the CPU to 16 threads would be a better? My rational that pinning the 16 threads would be that I would be spreading the load to 8 threads per physical CPU, therefore increasing the speed at which it could Turbo.

My workloads are generally a mix of single and multithreaded so performance on both types is important.

Comment: Trying to pin across NUMA nodes will probably dramatically reduce your performance. Let it go, and use the other CPU for something else.